# Watch Dogs: DX11 Error

Tags: watch-dogs

I have installed watch dogs but when I launch the watch_dogs.exe. The game won't run and will give me the error:

> WATCH_DOGS requires that your graphics hardware be compatible with
>   DirectX 11, and have the DirectX 11 runtime installed.

I have DirectX11 compatible GFX. I have run dxdiag and it clearly shows me that I have DX 11. I have also used GPU-Z, it shows me the same. I have tried a fix by watching these videos but are of no use:

[Video 1](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KxoMF_BLcWg)

[Video 2](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0B5KG2fv6ZI)

The fix works for them but not for me. Is there any other problem?

Comment: What is your graphics card?

Comment: @3ventic It is some GFX card by intel and I have DirectX 11. I'm not to sure about DirectX 11 Runtime. I have checked Program and Features in control panel and cannot find DX11 Runtime. IDK :D

Comment: Do I need to install this? http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=36805

Comment: I'm pretty sure Intel built-in GPU's are too weak to handle games like Watch_Dogs, even though its only complaint is DirectX 11.

Comment: Yeah @Rokk, It can't handle it.